# Positive number whose square exceeds its cube by the greatest amount

Tags: inequality, means, maxima-minima

> Find the positive number whose square exceeds its cube by the greatest amount.

Could you please help me with this question? It seems pretty easy at first glance, but I struggled to produce any answer. Thank you in advance!

UPD:
    Sorry, I didn't mention, but the exercise is to solve it without any differentiation.

Comment: You know that you don't need to look for $x > 1$ since the cubes are always strictly greater than the squares in that case.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^2 - x^3$.  So it reaches max/min when $f'(x) = 0$.  Solve (will get multiple answers.  It's a max if $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ and it is a min if $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$ and it is a saddle point if $f''(x) = 0$.  Solve and test.

Comment: Oh, you should also test if $f(x)$ is bounded above and has a maximum.

Comment: although that will be overkill.  x>1 x^2 < x^3.  0<x < 1 x^2 > x^3 and x <= 0 we only need to consider $x \in(0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that does not require calculus:

---

> Lemma: If $x+y+z = k$ (where $k$ is a constant), the product $xyz$ is maximized when $x=y=z= \dfrac k3 $

*Proof:*

By $AM-GM$, we have

$$\dfrac {x+y+z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3] {xyz}$$

$$\dfrac {k}{3} \ge \sqrt[3] {xyz}$$

$$\left(\dfrac {k}{3}\right)^3 \ge  xyz$$

We can see that the maximum of $xyz$ is $\left(\dfrac {k}{3}\right)^3$, with equality occurring $\iff x=y=z$

$$\left(\dfrac {k}{3}\right)^3 = x\cdot x \cdot x$$

$\implies x = \dfrac k3 $

$\implies x = y = z = \dfrac k3$

**Remark:** This lemma can be generalized for any $n$.

---

Now we want to find the maximum of $x^2 - x^3$, or equivalently

$$ f(x) = x\cdot x \cdot (1-x)$$

The maximum of $f$ occurs at the same $x$ value as the maximum of

$$g(x) = 2\cdot f(x) = x \cdot x \cdot (2-2x)$$

But notice that the factors in $g$ have a constant sum:

$$(x) + (x) + (2-2x) = 2$$

By the lemma, the product $x \cdot x \cdot (2-2x)$ reaches its maximum when $x = x = (2-2x) = \dfrac 23$

We can see that $x = \dfrac 23$, and the maximum is $$\left(\dfrac 23 \right )^2 - \left( \dfrac 23 \right)^3 = \dfrac {4}{27}$$

Comment: I was thinking that something like this should work, but I didn't have time to look into it, which is why I made for comment above. Nice job!

Comment: Thank you for answer! That's what I was really looking for. g(x)=2⋅f(x)=x⋅x⋅(2−2x) was the most crucial part that I didn't manage to get myself.

Comment: @Jevgenijus You're welcome!

Comment: By pure coincidence, this past weekend I happened to be looking over [*The turning-values of a cubic function and the nature of the roots of a cubic equation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BB9GAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA86) by Peter Pinkerton (1870-1930) [Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. (1) 22 (1904), pp. 86-89], and on the lower half of p. 86 Pinkerton uses the same method to determine the location of the maximum of $x(x-a)^2.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I learned this technique from a book called "Maxima and Minima Witouth Calculus"

Answer (score 1):

Let x be the number. We're trying to find the number $x$ where $x^2 > x^3$, and this is the biggest possible. So we're trying to find the $x$ that maximizes $x^2 - x^3$ We want $x^2 - x^3$ to be a maximum. 
Differentiate we get $2x - 3x^2$ and
set to zero, we find maximum at $x_1 = 0, x_2= \frac{2}{3}$ therefore $x=\frac{2}{3}$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is naturally expressed as a constrained optimisation problem:

$$ \max_{x} (x^2 - x^3) \quad \text{s.t} \quad x \geq 0 $$

It is also easy to see that the solution must be below 1.

Now you could go and use some fancy optimisation technique, such as formulating the Lagrangian, finding the critical points, verifying the KKT conditions with the constraint active... But here it's pretty much overkill.

Let $f(x) = x^2 - x^3$, then $f'(x) = 2x - 3x^2$. Every optimum is a critical point, so the optimal $x$ satisfies $2x = 3x^2$.

We want positive numbers, if $x = 0$ then $x^2 = x^3 = 0$. If $x \neq 0$ then $2 = 3x$ and $x = \frac{2}{3}$. For $x = \frac{2}{3}, \; x^2 - x^3 = \frac{4}{9} - \frac{8}{27} = \frac{4}{27}$.

So the solution is $x = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Possible student research project: Note that for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$ the function $x^2 - x^3 = x \cdot x \cdot (1-x)$ is maximized at a value equal to the arithmetic mean of where the individual functions $x,$ $x,$ and $1-x$ are maximized, that is, $\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1 + 1 + 0}{3}.$ Coincidence or something that can be generalized?

Comment: Thanks for the answers,@Mbahri . It was my mistake that I didn't mention that I am looking for solution that uses AM-GM inequality or any other "mean" inequality rather than 
differentiation. @Dave, could you better explain me your answer, please. Thanks!

Comment: @Jevgenijus: Not an answer, just an observation. The maximum of $x^2 - x^3$ on the interval $[0,1]$ (an interval on which it is non-negative) is equal to $\frac{2}{3}.$ Also, this function is the product of three functions ($x$ and $x$ and $1-x),$ each of which is non-negative on the same interval and each of which has a maximum on this interval. Moreover, the average of these three maximum values is equal to the maximum value of the original function. What if we had $8$ factors of $x$ multiplied by $5$ factors of $1-x$ --- would it still work out this way?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If you adjust the factors a little bit you can get the maximum from them alone (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

y = x^2 - x^3

We want the maximum point of the curve (where the square exceeds the cube by the highest amount) so we differentiate.

dy/dx = 2x - 3x^2

The maximum point is when dy/dx = 0 and d^2y/dx^2 (the second derivative) < 0

2x = 3x^2

x = 0 or 2 = 3x

x = 0 or 2/3

d^2y/dx^2 = 2 - 6x

Substitute in 0: d^2y/dx^2 = 2 so invalid value as d^2y/dx^2 should be < 0

Substitute in 2/3: d^2y/dx^2 = -2 so the answer is 2/3